# How can we execute a query only one time for all browsers while doing parallel execution

Tags: protractor, cucumber, cucumberjs

I am using protractor 5.2.2 and cucumber 3.2.0.I am doing a parallel execution by specifying multi capabilities as given below.

```
multiCapabilities: [
{
browserName: 'chrome',
},
{
browserName: 'chrome',
}],
```

i need to execute a query only one time for all browsers.But now that query is executing for each of the browsers.How can i set this query to be executed only one time when the script is run by the command 'protractor conf.js'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try the [beforeLaunch()](https://github.com/angular/protractor/blob/master/lib/config.ts#L459) of protractor conf.js.

```
  /**
   * A callback function called once configs are read but before any
   * environment setup. This will only run once, and before onPrepare.
   *
   * You can specify a file containing code to run by setting beforeLaunch to
   * the filename string.
   *
   * At this point, global variable 'protractor' object will NOT be set up,
   * and globals from the test framework will NOT be available. The main
   * purpose of this function should be to bring up test dependencies.
   */
  beforeLaunch?: () => void;
```

conf.js

```
  exports.config = {

      multiCapabilities: [],          

      specs:[],

      beforeLaunch: function(){
           // execute query at here
      }
      ...
  };
```

Comment: Great thanks yong..its worked for me.But if i have a parameter in beforeLaunch function and if i need to use that in my config file or some other fire,how can i access that from beforeLaunch function.

Comment: How do you specify the parameter value?  Passing-in from cmd line or hardcode in config file somewhere. Please show that.

Comment: I will get that parameter or a variable by executing a query at beforeLaunch function.My aim is to set multiCapabilities dynamically by this parameter or a variable from beforeLaunch function.I have explained it in this link "https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52772646/how-can-i-set-multicapabilities-dynamically-in-protractor-config-file"

Comment: young..is it possible to do like this?

Comment: Did you want to query DB posted in this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52754976/not-able-to-fetch-correct-data-while-executing-2-queries-in-beforeall-function-i to get the thread value then generate muliticapabilities according to thread value? If so I can mix the 3 question together to give a solution to fix it.

Comment: You can use `getMultiCapabilities()` : https://github.com/angular/protractor/blob/master/lib/config.ts#L392 in protractor conf.js to resolve your problem.

Comment: yes..i will get the thread value by calling a sp.But i need to call that sp only one time for all browsers.So i decided to call that sp in beforeLaunch function,So i will get thread value in beforeLaunch function and i have to use this to set the multiCapabilities dynamically.

Comment: getMultiCapabilities() is also be executed before any browser start and also for only one time. So no need to use `beforeLaunch()`. You can put all work inside  `getMultiCapabilities()`.

Comment: young..I am having a doubt that the functions in beforeLaunch and getMultiCapabilities get execute only once..that is when, once configs are read(before initial starting of the browser).Those functions will not execute even if we given a code for browser.restart(); in between our protractor script .Right?

Comment: yes, you are right. For more detail you can see the source code of protractor launcher: https://github.com/angular/protractor/blob/5.4.1/lib/launcher.ts#L111