# How can i set multiCapabilities dynamically in protractor config file

Tags: protractor, cucumberjs

I am using protractor 5.2.2. I have a requirement of setting multiCapabilities dynamically in protractor config file.Currently i have hard coded and set multiCapabilities as given below.

```
multiCapabilities: [
{
browserName: 'chrome',
BatchNo:1
},
{
browserName: 'chrome',
BatchNo:2
}],
```

i have a dynamic parameter called threads in beforeLaunch function.So depending on the value of this parameter, i have to set multiCapabilities dynamically and the BatchNo also.In above code i have threads=2, so i have 2 objects in multiCapabilities and BatchNo set as 1 and 2 respectively.If i have threads=4 in beforeLaunch function, then i have to set 4 objects in multiCapabilities and BatchNo should set as 1,2,3 and 4 respectively(i am using chrome browser for all threads).How can i do this.Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can use [getMultiCapabilities()](https://github.com/angular/protractor/blob/master/lib/config.ts#L392) to customize dynamical capabilites.

```
 /**
   * If you need to resolve multiCapabilities asynchronously (i.e. wait for 
   * server/proxy, set firefox profile, etc), you can specify a function here
   * which will return either `multiCapabilities` or a promise to
   * `multiCapabilities`.
   *
   * If this returns a promise, it is resolved immediately after
   * `beforeLaunch` is run, and before any driver is set up. If this is
   * specified, both capabilities and multiCapabilities will be ignored.
   */
  getMultiCapabilities?: any;
```

Define a function to get `thread` value.

```
let getThreadValue = function () {    
    return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {    
        request = new Request("sql to query thread value", function (err, rowCount, rows) {
            if (err) {
                reject(err);
            }
            else {
                resolve('put thread value at here');
            }
        });
        connection.execSql(request);   
    });
};
```

Use `getMultiCapabilities` in protractor conf.js:

```
exports.config = {

    seleniumAddress: 'http://localhost:4444/wd/hub',
    specs: ['./test.js'], 

    // If getMultiCapabilities is specified, 
    // both capabilities and multiCapabilities will be ignored
    getMultiCapabilities: function () {    
        return getThreadValue().then(function (thread) {
            let multiCapabilities = [];

            for (index = 1; index <= thread; index++) {
                multiCapabilities.push({
                    browserName: 'chrome',
                    BatchNo: index
                })
            }   
            return multiCapabilities;
        });
    }
};
```

Related code for further question about `beforeLaunch` issue:

```
let getThreadValue = function () { 
    return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) { 
        connection.on('connect', function (err) { 
            if (err) { 
                reject(err);
            } 
            else { 
                request = new Request("select * from location", function (err, rowCount, rows) { 
                    if (err) { 
                        reject(err); 
                    } else { 
                        resolve(Math.ceil(rowCount / 3)); 
                    } 
                }); 
                connection.execSql(request); 
            } 
        }); 
    }); 
};

beforeLaunch: function() {
    return getThreadValue().then(function (thread) {
        console.log('thread: ' + thread);

        return new Promise(function(resolve, reject){

            connection.on('connect', function (err) {
                if (err) {
                    reject(err);
                } else {
                    request = new Request("EXEC [usp_GetPostDetails] 1514," + thread, function (err, rowCount, rows) {
                        if (err) { 
                            reject(err); 
                        } else { 
                            console.log("done");
                            resolve('done');
                        }
                    });
                    connection.execSql(request);
                }
            });
        });
    });
}
```

Comment: Great thanks young..but when i used getThreadValue function in  beforeLaunch, for executing a query with the thread value, the query is not getting executing.and i am not understanding the issue there..could you pls help in this.I have added the code below

Comment: beforeLaunch: function(){
  return getThreadValue().then(function (thread) {
    console.log(thread);
    connection.on('connect', function(err) {
        if (err){
          console.log(err);
        }
        else{
            request = new Request("EXEC [usp_GetPostDetails] 1514,"+thread,function(err,rowCount, rows) {  
            console.log("done");
            });
            
            connection.execSql(request);
          
        }                
      });
   });
 },

Comment: Please show the function `getThreadValue()` in your question.

Comment: it is same as in your answer.i will get the thread value from getThreadValue function and using this thread value i need to set the multiCapabilities dynamically and also need to execute other one query also(both these queries should execute only at one time for all browsers).i have added the getThreadValue() below

Comment: let getThreadValue = function () {    
        return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) { 
          connection.on('connect', function(err) {
            if (err){
              console.log(err);
            }
            else{   
              request = new Request("select * from location", function (err, rowCount, rows) {
                if (err) {
                    reject(err);
                }
                else {
                    resolve(Math.ceil(rowCount/3));
                } });
             connection.execSql(request);
      }  });    });  };

Comment: I give the updated code of  `beforeLaunch` in my answer, please try it to see the query inside `beforeLauch` will be executed or not.

Comment: its not executing the query inside beforeLauch .it stuck after printing thread: 4 in console.

Comment: i am not sure..it may be due to multiple db connections.If i am not using connection.on('connect', function (err) in beforeLaunch, it will execute the query inside beforeLaunch. But then it is not catching the getMultiCapabilities.How can we solve this?

Comment: Great thanks young.the error occurred while trying to connect with DB multiple times..now i am able handle the connection only at first time.So its running perfectly..

Answer (score 0):

`multiCapabilities` should get `Array<string>`. You could create a variable that will have a function that returns specific array corresponding to your condition.
For example:

firstly create a function that create your own `multiCapabilities` array

```
function createArray(threads) {
  const array = [];
  for (let batch = 1; batch <= threads; batch++) {
    array.push({
      browserName: 'chrome',
      BatchNo: batch
    });
  }
  return array;
}
```

create variable that returns specific `multiCapabilities` corresponding to your threads

```
const myMultiCapabilities = (threads) => {
  return createArray(threads);
}
```

and finally use it for setting `multiCapabilities`:

```
multiCapabilities: myMultiCapabilities(threads)
```